# Running for range with a goroutine inside a for range

Tags: go

I have a goroutine inside a loop and I want to execute a goroutine for each item in ms.Entries concurrently but it's only running for the last item in the loop.

I've abstracted my example out of a larger program...
https://play.golang.org/p/whUMQ3pjq81

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Entry   *Entry
    Entries *[]Entry
}

type Entry struct {
    ID   int
    Name string
}

type Fn struct {
    Res string
    Err error
}

func main() {
    e1 := Entry{ID: 1, Name: "First"}
    e2 := Entry{ID: 2, Name: "Second"}

    ms := &MyStruct{
        Entries: &[]Entry{e1, e2},
    }

    fmt.Printf("MS: %+v\n", ms)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    fnChan := make(chan *Fn)
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(fnChan)
    }()

    var fns []func() (string, error)
    fns = append(fns, ms.actionA)
    fns = append(fns, ms.actionB)

    for i, entry := range *ms.Entries {
        fmt.Printf("%d: %+v\n", i, entry)
        ms.Entry = &entry
        for j, fn := range fns {
            fmt.Printf("fn loop %d\n", j)
            wg.Add(1)
            go ms.process(&wg, fn, fnChan)
        }
    }

    for d := range fnChan {
        fmt.Printf("fnchan: %+v\n", d)
    }
}

func (m *MyStruct) actionA() (string, error) {
    fmt.Println("actionA")
    fmt.Printf("Entry: %s\n", m.Entry.Name)
    return "actionA done", nil
}

func (m *MyStruct) actionB() (string, error) {
    fmt.Println("actionB")
    fmt.Printf("Entry: %s\n", m.Entry.Name)
    return "actionB done", nil
}

func (m *MyStruct) process(wg *sync.WaitGroup, fn func() (string, error), fnChan chan<- *Fn) {
    fmt.Println("processing")
    var err error
    defer wg.Done()

    res, err := fn()
    if err != nil {
        fnChan <- &Fn{Err: err}
        return
    }

    fnChan <- &Fn{Res: res}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Adrian the question, in case it wasn't obvious, was; why is my goroutine only using the last element in the slice and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

You have a problem here:

```
ms.Entry = &entry
```

When you use a loop, like this:

```
for i, entry := range *ms.Entries {
```

The variable "entry" is only declared once.

So `&entry` will have a constant value (same value in every iteration).

But even if you solve that issue, another problem is that you are using the same `ms` object on every iteration.

So when you then launch different goroutines, the `ms.Entry = ...` statement you execute on the second iteration is modifying the shared `ms` object.

You are also "sharing" the `fn` variable between iterations as described in the other answer, so you should also capture that variable.

**Fix**

I suggest you remove the `Entry` field from your struct (you don't need it since you already have the complete array), and you use the array position to refer to the current entry.

You should add an `i int` parameter to your "action" and "process" functions.

You also need to "capture" the `fn` variable.

```
for i, entry := range *ms.Entries {
    ...
    for j, fn := range fns {
        ...
        fn := fn // capture the fn variable
        go ms.process(&wg, fn, fnChan, i) // sending index here
    }
}
```

See here for a modified playground:

https://play.golang.org/p/uuw7r4kGBPb

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation and example @eugenioy

Answer (score 3):

You have been caught by this trap : [Using goroutines on loop iterator variables](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables)

---

One way to fix this :

```
    for j, fn := range fns {
        fmt.Printf("fn loop %d\n", j)
        wg.Add(1)

        // copy the iterator variable to a local variable :
        // variables declared within the body of a loop are not shared between iterations
        f := fn
        go ms.process(&wg, f, fnChan)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for that link, it helped me understand the situation better. Your example wasn't the solution but def a part of it @LeGEC